# Neo4j: full-text lucene legacy indexes (node_auto_index) does not work after migration

Tags: neo4j, lucene, migration, database-migration, fuzzy-search

After successful migration from Neo4j 2.2.8 to 3.0.4 using [official faq](https://neo4j.com/guides/upgrade/#neo4j-3-0), full text search does not work as expected. Fuzziness is not that fuzzy as it was before.

Example:

```sql
START n=node:node_auto_index('name:(+Target~0.85)') MATCH (n) RETURN n;
```

Should return nodes with field `name` that contain work like 85% similar to 'Target'.

Before it was matching the following:

1. Target
2. Target v2

After migration:

1. Target

Why and how to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason was that after migration lucene `node_auto_index` wasn't configured properly. Probably migration tools does not respect its configuration or broken.

The solution was to setup indexes correctly and rebuild them.

Steps:

1. Check your `/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf` that auto_index is enabled and keys are set to fields that you want to auto index:

```
dbms.auto_index.nodes.enabled=true                                                                                                                                                                                 
dbms.auto_index.nodes.keys=name
```

2. Check that `node_auto_index` configured correctly by running:

```sh
neo4j-shell -c 'index --get-config node_auto_index'
{
    "analyzer": "org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer",
    "provider": "lucene",
    "to_lower_case": "true",
    "type": "fulltext"
}
```

3. If it does not meet your requirements, for example `type` is not `fulltext` then you run following:

```sh
neo4j-shell -c 'index --set-config node_auto_index type fulltext'
neo4j-shell -c 'index --set-config node_auto_index to_lower_case true'
neo4j-shell -c 'index --set-config node_auto_index analyzer org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer'
```

3. After that you need to re-index your data. Based on `dbms.auto_index.nodes.keys` setting (`name` field in this example), run the following cypher on your data set:

```sql
MATCH (n) WHERE EXISTS(n.name) WITH (n) SKIP 0 LIMIT 50000 SET n.name=n.name;
MATCH (n) WHERE EXISTS(n.name) WITH (n) SKIP 50000 LIMIT 50000 SET n.name=n.name;
MATCH (n) WHERE EXISTS(n.name) WITH (n) SKIP 100000 LIMIT 50000 SET n.name=n.name;
// ...
```

The following steps will help you to setup full-text lucene indexes in Neo4j 3.0 and re-index your existing data.

Comment: can we do this via remote hosted neo4j with java configuration ?

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoman I am not sure that you can do point 1). The others might be possible. I do not use Java driver for myself but my driver is less advanced.