# Neo4j 3.x and lucene

Tags: neo4j, lucene

I install lucene in linux (ubuntu) and want to configure Lucene for it.
After searching I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39268710/neo4j-full-text-lucene-legacy-indexes-node-auto-index-does-not-work-after-mig) but

> dbms.auto_index.nodes.enabled=true
>   dbms.auto_index.nodes.keys=name

not exist on neo4j 3.x.
Can anyone help me for configure lucene in neo4j?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I need configure lucene index in neo4j 3.x, Old configuration (neo4j 2.x) removed in version 3.x and I cannot use old configruration.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39268710/neo4j-full-text-lucene-legacy-indexes-node-auto-index-does-not-work-after-mig